# How to get the Index of a DataFrame when using the chunksize argument?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very big `.csv` file which I cant load fully into my RAM. That's why I need to load my dataset witch the `chunksize` argument like this:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv("challenger_match_V2.csv", chunksize=100, iterator=True)
```

But how do I access the dataset with the index.
Without using the chunksize argument I can just do `dataframe[idx:idx]`.
How can I do that with chunksize

I tried doing:

```
for chunk in csv:
    print(chunk[idx])
```

which didn't work I got a KeyError with the index I tried to access the dataframe.

Example:

```
for chunk in csv:
    print(chunk[5])
```

Which gave the error:

```
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 5
```

Comment: What variable is i? If i remeber right, each chunk is a df. Maybe try chunk[i]

Comment: Sry my bad. Fixed it in the answer. The problem still persist.

Comment: This is a totally different solution from what you're expecting - but could be easier: Have you tried running your code on google colab? you get around 12 GB of ram for free.

Comment: i myself have 16gb ram :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up throwing away some data from my dataframe to reduce the amount of memory needed.

Answer (score 1):

Each pandas chunk return value is an iterable object of type TextFileReader instead of a DataFrame so you can't index it like any regular DataFrame. Instead, you need iterate over `csv = pd.read_csv("challenger_match_V2.csv", chunksize=100, iterator=True)` and concat each chunk to get a DataFrame. You can also append each chunk to a list then concat the whole list.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv("challenger_match_V2.csv", chunksize=100, iterator=True)

for chunk in csv:
    df = pd.concat(chunk)
    print(df)
```

OR

```
import pandas as pd

csv = pd.read_csv("challenger_match_V2.csv", chunksize=100, iterator=True)
chunk_list = []

for chunk in csv:
    chunk_list.append(chunk)

df = pd.concat(chunk_list)
print(df)
```

You can also print each chunk by just doing `print(chunk)` will iterating.

Comment: when I concatenate my dataframe in the end. That defeats the purpose of using chunksize. I use chunksize because the dataframe is to BIG for my memory. When i split my dataframe to chunk and concatenate it in the end it will be so big when I just load it into my memory

Comment: I don't set iterator to True and my chunks are dfs, weird.